# Find value of infinite sum

Tags: sequences-and-series

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I evaluate $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2n}{3^{n+1}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30732/how-can-i-evaluate-sum-n-1-infty-frac2n3n1)

How would I go about deriving the value of the following infinite sum: $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty kx^k$ ?

I thought about expanding first: $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty kx^k= x + 2x^2 + 3x^3 + \cdots$

Then a bit of algebra: $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty kx^k - \sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty (k-1)x^k = x + x^2 + x^3 + \cdots + 1 -1 $

And now I'm stuck with this: $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty x^k = \frac{x}{1-x}$

How can I introduce the $k$ into $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty x^k$ ? Or is there a different approach that I don't know of?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30732/how-can-i-evaluate-sum-n-1-infty-frac2n3n1) for ideas.

Comment: Thanks @David. I got the idea from Jonas Meyer's answer. Briefly, I would rewrite: $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty kx^k = x(1 + x + x^2 + ...) + x^2(1 + x^2 + ...) + ... = x(1+ x + x^2 + ...)^2$. Then $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty kx^k = \frac{x}{(1-x)^2}$.

Comment: There must be at least five duplicates of this question...

Comment: @Hans Indeed. I voted to close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you know $\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k$ you can differentiate the result. Justify that you can differentiate the series term-by-term.

Comment: Oh, differentiation of course.

Comment: Thanks @Jochen Wengenroth. I differentiate both sides here: $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty x^k = \frac{x}{1-x}$. Then I get: $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty kx^(k-1) = \frac{1}{(1-x)^2}$. I then multiply both sides by $x$ and I get my answer.

Answer (score 3):

$$\begin{align}
   \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}kx^k&=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(k+1)x^k-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}x^k\\
&=\left(\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}x^{k+1}\right)^{\prime}-\frac{x}{1-x}\\
&=\left(\frac{x^2}{1-x}\right)^{\prime}-\frac{x}{1-x}\\
&=\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}
\end{align}$$
Here $|x|<1$.