# Sum of two random variables with $Geo(p)$ distribution

Tags: probability

I need to prove that the following expression is a probability function

$$P(X+Y=k)={k+1\choose k}(1-p)^k p^2$$ with $$k=0,1,...$$

First of all is easy to verify that $f(x) \ge 0$, the problem comes when verifying that the sum adds up to 1, so far I have:

\begin{align}
P(X+Y=k) &= \sum_{x=0}^{k} P(X=x, Y=k-x)
\\& = \sum_{x=0}^{k} P(X=x) P(Y=k-x)
\\& = \sum_{x=0}^{k} (1-p)^xp(1-p)^{k-x}p
\\& = (k+1) (1-p)^k p^2
\end{align}

But now I'm stuck proving that that function sums 1, I imagine I must use the definition of $geo(p)$ but I don't really know how, can someone give me a hint on what to do next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to show that
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} P(X+Y=k) = 1
$$
Note that
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} P(X+Y=k) 
&=p^2\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (k+1)(1-p)^k\\
&=p^2 + p^2\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (k+1)(1-p)^k\\
&=p^2 + p^2 \left [\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} k(1-p)^k + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (1-p)^k \right ]\\
&=p^2 + p^2 \left [\frac{1-p}{p^2} + \frac{1-p}{p} \right ]\\
&= 1
\end{align*}

The first summation is evaluated by using this [result](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/136338), and the second is a standard geometric series

Answer (score 0):

With $q:=1-p$, note that
\begin{align}
S &= \sum_{k = 0}^\infty (k+1) q^k
\\
S &= 1 + 2 q + 3 q^2 + \cdots
\\
S &= (1 + q + q^2 + \cdots) + q(1 + 2q + 3q^2 + \cdots)
\\
S &= \frac{1}{1-q} + qS
\\
S &= \frac{1}{(1-q)^2}
\end{align}